# CHECK if the column values in a table add upto 100 (percentage)

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working on an assignment in MYSQL. There is a column in a table that tracks the percentage of commission for an author. The commission value in the tuples should always add up to 100

> R is the relation R ={authorid,isbn,commission} 
>   (authorid,isbn) --> primary key

So the tuples can include multiple authors for an isbn each with a different value of the commission. We should ensure for a isbn the commission should always add up to 100 not less or more. How do I implement this? I was told to use triggers to implement the same, however, I ran out of ideas.

I can only think of a trigger something like below (high-level logic)

```
SELECT isbn,sum(commission) FROM R GROUP BY isbn
```

I get the total commission and check if the value is 100 or not and then reject insertion/updation based on that

But this means I will reject cases where the user wants to insert 3 tuples sequentially where the commission is 20,30,50 respectively. This is a valid case. The insertion would look like below

```
INSERT INTO R(authorid,isbn,commission) VALUES (1,2,20)
INSERT INTO R(authorid,isbn,commission) VALUES (2,2,30)
INSERT INTO R(authorid,isbn,commission) VALUES (3,2,50)
```

Could you please guide me on this? Please do let me know if I wasn't clear. I feel like it is unusual to do this kind of validation on the database side, however, this is an assignment so should come up with some solution

I have looked on web if something similar has been already solved. Looked at MYSQL documentation and no luck.

Comment: You should add some data, so that we cann see how your 20,30,50 are produced. see  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Added some insertion statements. Hope that helps

Comment: How would you determine that there would always be 3 rows for an author. I meant to ask, Why user should get the error only during insert of 3rd row, while 1st or 2nd row itself are not adding up to 100?

Comment: it was just an example. The case you are talking about is also valid

Comment: From my perspective, I thought this is not possible to implement as we don't know what values the user would possibly insert in the future. But I would like to get that confirmed from some of the experts here

Answer (score 0):

You can use for insert

this trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER commisiontest
BEFORE INSERT ON R
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT sum(commission) into @commision FROM R  WHERE isbn = NEw.isbn GROUP BY isbn;
  IF (NEW.commission + @commision) > 100
  THEN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Warning: commission reaches 100 or above';
  END IF;

END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

This would make this

```
INSERT INTO R(authorid,isbn,commission) VALUES (3,2,50) 
Error Code: 1643. Warning: commission reaches 100 or above  0.000 sec
```

Something similar also goes for update

So this will prevent commision that are higher that 100 procent

Comment: The commission is the percentage of income that an author gets if an isbn is sold. This percentage of the money (commission) they keep should be distributed among the authors of a book. The trigger here would only stop from inserting records if the commission has reached beyond 100. But they are cases where first 2 records(refer to my question insert statements 1 & 2) only can be inserted which means the commission total is only 50

Comment: INSERT INTO R(authorid,isbn,commission) VALUES (1,2,20)
INSERT INTO R(authorid,isbn,commission) VALUES (2,2,30) If the user only runs these 2 statements it shouldn't be considered as valid as the commission didn't add upto 100. I don't think your trigger would throw a warning in such cases

Comment: My professor agreed that this assignment needs changing and the question is rephrased as all the values of commission for an isbn shouldn't add up to more than 100. The solution posted by you would work in that case

Comment: i gave it some thought, but you need another algorithm. you should write the tsbke structure down  and then write what happens when you sell one book and finally how that ibteracts with the percentage. What  you are doing, is only entering teh percentage and my trigger only would prevent that the percentage goes over 100 per cent.